# jQuery - Increase the value of a counter when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I'm making a system where a user clicks a button and their score increases. There is a counter which I would like to increase the value of using jQuery (so that the page does not need to refresh) when the button is clicked.

How would I go about this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#update").click(function() {
$("#counter")++;
}

</script>
```

#update is the button, #counter is the counter.

In php, ++ increases something's value. What's the jQuery equivalent?

Also, when the button is clicked, it needs to send a request which updates the score value in a mysql database as well, without the page refreshing. Does anyone know how I would do that?

Thanks a lot

UPDATE:

I've tried a few of the methods below, but nothing seems to work! Do I need to change anything else for it to work? I've created a test page for it:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var count = 0;

$("#update").click(function() {
    count++;
    $("#counter").html("My current count is: "+count);
}

</script>
<button id="update" type="button">Button</button>
<div id="counter">1</div>
</body>
</htlm>
```

Comment: *#counter is the counter*: Is it an element containing a number or what?

Comment: yeah, #counter is a div with a number inside

Comment: @Taimur your code is not valid. End your click function with `});` and not just `}`. **DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/Bwdfw/

Comment: I tried that, and I also tried literally copying and pasting your second demo thing, but it is not working :( 

If it helps, I'm using WAMP server and the test page is a .php page, but I'm pretty sure that doesn't matter

Comment: Don't know if you solved your problem, but you have to wrap your code in to the document ready handler. Currently jQuery does not find the element with ID `#button` because it is not parsed yet. Put your code into `$(function(){ your code here });`. (and the already mentioned missing `);` at the end of your click handler passing. What you have is `$(..).click(...` but you need `$(...).click(...);`).

Comment: it's because you're trying to execute your code without waiting for the DOM to be ready for jQuery: look at my edited answer below:

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You cannot use `++` on something which is not a variable, this would be the closest you can get:

```
$('#counter').html(function(i, val) { return +val+1 });
```

jQuery's [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method can get and set the HTML value of an element. If passed a function it can update the HTML based upon the existing value. So in the context of your code:

```
$("#update").click(function() {
    $('#counter').html(function(i, val) { return +val+1 });
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/zRX2D/2/

When it comes to synchronising your counter on the page, with the counter value in your database, **never trust the client!** You send either an increment or decrement signal to you server side script, rather than a continuous value such  as 10, or 23.

However you could send an AJAX request to the server when you change the HTML of your counter:

```
$("#update").click(function() {
    $('#counter').html(function(i, val) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/script/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {increment: true},
            success: function() { alert('Request has returned') }
        });
        return +val+1;
    });
}
```

Comment: This works fine in the demo thing, but for some reason, it's not working on my page. In fact, none of the answers are! 

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 

regarding the AJAX thing, how does it know whether the function was a success? Also, what does (i,val) do?
Thanks

Comment: @Marcus Consider `+val + 1` instead of `val * 1 + 1`

Comment: Take a look at the [jQuery docs for AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details. Any request that returns with HTTP 200 is "successful". jQuery's `html()` method can accept a callback which is passed two values the index of the current element in the jQuery selector `i`, and the current HTML value of that element `val`. Again see the [jQuery docs for more information](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2).

Comment: @Sime is it more efficient since it is arithmetic instead of multiplication?

Comment: @Marcus I don't think that efficiency is an issue here. Both methods take approx. 17 picoseconds to execute `:D`. It's readability that I care about. The unary plus operator is the most readable method of casting a string into a number.

Comment: if you just copy and paste into what you have currently, almost none of it will work because you're missing jQuery's "ready" function - $(document).ready

Answer (score 21):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var count = 0;

  $("#update").click(function() {
    count++;
    $("#counter").html("My current count is: "+count);
  }

});

<div id="counter"></div>
```

Comment: you needed to add the document ready function before firing any jQuery code (edited above)

Answer (score 10):

It's just

```
var counter = 0;

$("#update").click(function() {
   counter++;
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Several of the suggestions above use global variables. This is not a good solution for the problem. The count is specific to one element, and you can use jQuery's [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function to bind an item of data to an element:

```
$('#counter').data('count', 0);
$('#update').click(function(){
    $('#counter').html(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            count = $this.data('count') + 1;

        $this.data('count', count);
        return count;
    });
});
```

Note also that this uses the callback syntax of [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to make the code more fluent and fast.

Comment: Not true if there's more than one way of changing the value of count

Comment: @j3frea Then encapsulate the code in a plugin. Honestly, this isn't hard to do, and littering your code with global variables is very bad design.

Comment: Nobody is using global variables, they are just examples. The context is not stated in any answer.

Comment: Don't forget to initialize the counter beforehand, otherwise it won't work: `$('#counter').data('count', 0);`

Comment: @Sime Thanks. I always want `undefined` to equal `0` in mathematical operations... @Marcus Well, some are. Constraining the context should be an integral part of the answer, in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the below site and tryout. 
http://www.counter12.com/

From the above link I have selected the one design that I liked to have in my site accepted terms and it has given me a div that I have pasted in my html page.

It did awesomely worked.

I am not answering to your problem on JQuery, but giving you an alternate solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set "++" on a jQuery element!

YOu could declare a js variable

```
var counter = 0;
```

and in jQuery code do:

```
$("#counter").html(counter++);
```

Comment: You should create a global variable? Really?

Comment: "You SHOULD" ;) not "you MUST" ..it would be better "you could".. c'mon there are several ways to do this, mine it's just a suggestion!

Comment: Yes, "you could" is the correct form here. "You should" is for recommendations. And no one should recommend creating global variables, the recommendation here is the opposite: one should try to avoid creating global variables.

Comment: You're absolutely right! "global" word is my bad ;) I apologize

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try this the following way. I've placed the count variable inside the "onfocus" function so as to keep it from becoming a global variable. The idea is to create a counter for each image in a tumblr blog.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#image1").onfocus(function() {

  var count;

    if (count == undefined || count == "" || count == 0) {
    var count = 0;
    }

    count++;
    $("#counter1").html("Image Views: " + count);
  }
});
```

Then, outside the script tags and in the desired place in the body I'll add:

```
<div id="counter1"></div>
```