# Jquery : How to show number of clicks?

Tags: jquery, count

I'm starting to learn JQuery.

Right now I want to take the value from my paragraph and give it +1 everytime I click on it.
This is what I've tried:

```
<body>
    <p>0</p>
    <script>
        $("p").click(function(){
            // code...
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

This is my script

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701349/jquery-increase-the-value-of-a-counter-when-a-button-is-clicked

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/124/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as simple as this:

```
$(function(){ // you can wrap it here with in document ready block
   var i = 0;
   $("p").click(function(){
       $(this).html(i++);
   });
});
```

or may be a better one:

```
$(function(){ // you can wrap it here with in document ready block
   $("p").click(function(){
       $(this).html(+this.textContent + 1);
   });
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czXU6/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  $( "p" ).click(function(){
     $(this).html(parseInt($(this).html(),10)+1);
  });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Uu9yh/)**

Comment: The second argument to `parseInt` is *not* optional.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol But by default it will take that arg as `10`

Comment: False. By default it will take that argument as `0`, which is a special value meaning "guess". Try parsing `0x123` with and without the argument and tell me they're the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
var count=0;
$( "p" ).click(function(){
    count++;    
    $(this).text(count);
});
```

Comment: You could add a description of how your code works, since you answer to a beginner...

Answer (score 0):

```
this.firstChild.nodeValue = +this.firstChild.nodeValue + 1;
```

MOSR EFFICIENTS! :p

Comment: `+this.firstChild.nodeValue` part is having the vulnerability to return `NAN`