# Increment Rails model column with Ajax/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, audio

I'm having trouble incrementing an integer column (`plays`) for the `tracks` model in a Rails music app. Users can play tracks in the app using buttons like this one:

```
<% @top_tracks.each do |track| %>
  <button class="track-play track-<%= track.id %>-play" onclick="playTrack(<%= track.to_json %>)">
    <i class="icon-play"></i>
  </button>
  ...
  [info about the track, such as <%= track.title %>]
  ...
<% end %>
```

And here are the relevant parts of the corresponding Javascript:

```
var player = document.getElementById('audio');

window.playTrack = function (track) {
    player.setAttribute('src', track.file_url);
    player.play();
};
```

I have read through answers to somewhat similar questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4701358/4163426), that suggest utilizing Ajax/Javascript, but I'm not sure how to do that to get the desired result in my case. I don't even know if Ajax/Javascript is the best way to achieve what I'm looking for.

What should happen is that every time a track is played and the `playTrack()` function is called, the value of the `plays` column for that track should be incremented by 1 and then (obviously) the new value for `plays` should be saved in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your every track button add a `data attribute` say, `data-track`

```
<% @top_tracks.each do |track| %>
  <button data-track="#{track.id}" class="track-play track-<%= track.id %>-play" onclick="playTrack(<%= track.to_json %>)">
    <i class="icon-play"></i>
  </button>

<% end %>
```

in your **routes.rb** lets say declare:

```
post '/update_track_info', as: 'update_track_info', to: 'tracks#update_track_info'
```

create an ajax request:

```
window.playTrack = function (track) {
    player.setAttribute('src', track.file_url);
    player.play();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/update_track_info',
      data: { track_id: $(this).data('track').val() },
      type: 'POST'
    }) 

};
```

Then on the controller action:

```
def update_track_info
 @track = Track.find(params[:track_id].to_i)
 @track.update_column(:plays, @track.plays.next)    
 render :nothing => true
end
```

Comment: can you show me how to connect the url in the ajax request to the method in the controller?

Comment: I'm getting a 400 (Bad Request) error. Looks like it's not recognizing the rails path in the url, because the GET url associated with the error is: `http://localhost:3000/%3C%=%20update_track_info_path()%20%%3E?track_id=14`

Comment: where did you put the controller action? It should be written in `tracks_controller.rb` file.

Comment: The controller action is in the `tracks_controller.rb` file. It seems like the url being passed in by the ajax isn't coming through properly as noted by my last comment

Comment: `get '/update_track_info', as: 'update_track_info', to: 'tracks#update_track_info'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88969/discussion-between-andrew-and-emu).